# purely command-line operation of dropbox

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin, dropbox

Is it possible to make use of dropbox account from purely command-line solution e.g a bash script?

I have so far failed to find a comprehensive answer to this question.

I have used Git for sometime now and it is quite easy to use from commandline. If dropbox does not have a robust command-line version then what alternatives exist to dropbox which do have this feature?

Since we are approaching end of 2020, maybe things have changed. I use windows but will access dropbox through Cygwin which is basically a way to access Linux like functionality in windows.

Comment: Perhaps not "purely command line" and with a somewhat steep learning curve (the Dropbox API, that is) but [Python](https://www.python.org/) and [the official Dropbox module for Python](https://pypi.org/project/dropbox/) can be used to create Python scripts that can be used to access and manipulate a given Dropbox account.

Comment: OK I really did not expect there to be a PyPi for Dropbox. So I guess any solution that anyone comes up with will be a wrapper around this Python module then?

Comment: I haven't broken it down personally, but it wouldn't be surprising. Dropbox uses Python heavily, at least as far as I am aware. This [ZDNet article from October 2019](https://www.zdnet.com/article/python-programming-language-creator-retires-saying-its-been-an-amazing-ride/) states *"Dropbox has about four million lines of Python code and it's the most heavily used language for its back-end services and desktop app."*

Answer (score 5):

#### Make use of dropbox account from purely command-line solution?

Have you tried [dbxcli](http://%5Bdropbox/dbxcli:%20A%20command%20line%20client%20for%20Dropbox%20built%20using%20the%20Go%20SDK%5D(https://github.com/dropbox/dbxcli))?

> **dbxcli: A command line tool for Dropbox users and team admins**
>
> Features
>
> - Supports basic file operations like ls, cp, mkdir, mv (via the Files API)
> - Supports search
> - Supports file revisions and file restore
> - Chunked uploads for large files, paginated listing for large directories
> - Supports a growing set of Team operations
>
> Installation
>
> Download pre-compiled binaries for Mac, Windows and Linux from the
> releases page.

...

> ```
> $ dbxcli --help
> Use dbxcli to quickly interact with your Dropbox, upload/download files,
> manage your team and more. It is easy, scriptable and works on all platforms!
>
> Usage:
>   dbxcli [command]
>
> Available Commands:
>   cp          Copy files
>   du          Display usage information
>   get         Download a file
>   ls          List files
>   mkdir       Create a new directory
>   mv          Move files
>   put         Upload files
>   restore     Restore files
>   revs        List file revisions
>   rm          Remove files
>   search      Search
>   team        Team management commands
>   version     Print version information
>
> Flags:
>       --as-member string   Member ID to perform action as
>   -v, --verbose            Enable verbose logging
>
> Use "dbxcli [command] --help" for more information about a command.
>
> $ dbxcli team --help
> Team management commands
>
> Usage:
>   dbxcli team [command]
>
> Available Commands:
>   add-member    Add a new member to a team
>   info          Get team information
>   list-groups   List groups
>   list-members  List team members
>   remove-member Remove member from a team
>
> Global Flags:
>       --as-member string   Member ID to perform action as
>   -v, --verbose            Enable verbose logging
>
> Use "dbxcli team [command] --help" for more information about a command.
> ```

Source: [dropbox/dbxcli: A command line client for Dropbox built using the Go SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dbxcli)

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about this. This does not seem to be created by Dropbox themself but is some 3rd party solution. Is this true?

Comment: It's open source written by various developers.

Answer (score 4):

Dropbox supports under Linux an official command-line interface via the
[dropbox command](https://www.mankier.com/1/dropbox).
One needs to navigate to the root of the actual Dropbox folder before running
the commands below, which is usually `~/Dropbox`.

```
dropbox update
dropbox filestatus [-l] [-a] [FILE]...
dropbox ls [FILE]...
dropbox puburl FILE
dropbox sharelink FILE
dropbox proxy MODE [TYPE] [HOST] [PORT] [USERNAME] [PASSWORD]
dropbox throttle DOWNLOAD UPLOAD
dropbox status
dropbox running
dropbox stop
dropbox lansync [y/n]
dropbox exclude [list]
dropbox start [-i]
dropbox autostart [y/n]
dropbox version
dropbox help [COMMAND]
```

For more information see the Dropbox help article
[What Linux commands are available on Dropbox?](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/linux-commands#commands)

Comment: Is the root at C:\Program Files (x86)\Drop box    ?

Comment: The "What Linux commands are available on Dropbox?" on the dropbox website lists some commands but when I type dropbox into cygwin, it says it cannot identity the command. If I goto in the Client folder of Dropbox installation and execute dropbox.exe, I find that this executeable is not meant for commandline calling.

Comment: Possibly the installation under Cygwin is not complete. But why are you using Cygwin when WSL under Windows 10 offers real Linux distributions?

Comment: @harrymc Those distros are in a VM, so can't directly access things outside it (iirc).

Comment: That's not true - WSL can refer to the Windows file system using `/mnt` and can also use internet. This isn't a real VM.

Comment: Sorry guys I don't know about WSL. I just inherited Cygwin in my project. Downloading new packages is easy, we just open the setup and download them. Is it so easy to do with WSL as well?

Comment: [How to install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/install-windows-subsystem-linux-windows-10).